# Multiple SSL certificates for specific domains - Flask

Tags: ssl, flask

I have a directory to store certificates and have the domains stored in a database with their SSL certificate path

For example I have:

```
certs_dir:
   - localhost1.pem
   - localhost1.key
   - localhost2.pem
   - localhost2.key
```

And I have 2 different domains like `localhost1/index` and `localhost2/index`, they both are hosting on the same Flask app

I want each domain to use It's own SSL using Flask

Is it even possible? If yes, then how?

I don't want to run my flask application with `ssl_context`, I want to lookup SSL Certificate for the route in my middleware and decide which cert to use for this request on response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLS handshake, and hence choosing which certificate to present, happens before any HTTP exchange.

It is only at the HTTP exchange step that the full URL is exchanged between the client. Before that, and during the TLS handshake, the client has sent (through TLS SNI extension) only the **hostname** of the server it tries to contact.

Hence a server can only base itself on the hostname requested to decide which certificate to send back to client.

So, no, your case where only the local path in the URL changes (as it was the case with the original version of the question: `localhost/cert1` vs `localhost/cert2`) can not provoke separate certificates. You could do that if you used different hostnames: `realm1.example.com` and `realm2.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, different domains was what I wanted to say, I edited the question a little, is it possible to do this if there are different domains? How?

Comment: If the hostname is different, then it is possible in general yes. How it is done with your specific framework, I do not know.

Comment: Based on the lack of documentation for such cases in both Flask and Werkzeug and the way the connection is started in the latter (see https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/serving.py#L602) I do not believe it is possible to do what you want, at least not at the configuration level. You would need to override `BaseWSGIServer.__init__` and use `SSLContext.set_servername_callback` from Python `ssl` module to grab the hostname given during SNI and establish the proper SSLContext at that moment, when the client is connecting...

Comment: The alternative is to put a webserver such as nginx or Apache in front of your application and let TLS terminates there. Then from it to your application it is pure HTTP traffic without the need of certificates. This of course has security implications.